# eCommerce Payment Gateway with no percentage transaction fee?

Tags: web-development, online-payment, donation

We're looking to set up a site to take donations for a charity. I've been looking at payment gateway and eCommerce services such as [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/), [Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/), [Highwire](http://www.highwire.com/pricing), and others. I came across a few comparison sites like [this](http://www.formstack.com/payment-gateway-comparison) and I have some questions, and would also like recommendations on which platform to use.

My main confusion seems to be that some sites claim to have a 0% transaction fee - but when investigating further, it's because they don't actually collect the payments, but instead allow for integration with another payment gateway who will then take a percentage of the funds. **Are there services that offer a flat rate (subscription or per transaction or both) for collecting funds through credit card payments?** Is it possible to use Authorize.Net or similar gateway without going through a reseller who will collect a percentage?

Basic requirements:

- Compatible with Windows OR OS independent / browser based
- Doesn't require domain to be bought through them (we already have the .org site)
- Low transaction fee percentage as possible (flat rate is fine - donations will be in the hundreds of dollars or more range)
- Processes credit card transactions

Bonus:

- Site and store management accessible through a WYSIWYG editor
- Accepts credit cards of as many varieties as possible (Visa, MasterCard, AmEx, etc)
- Reports (sales #'s, statistics)
- Processes e-checks or debit card transactions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *SERVICE* recommendation, not *SOFTWARE* recommendation (see: [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)).